# SharePoint 2010 Compatibility with Office 2013 on Client

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-office, office-2013

Hi We have a web based SharePoint 2010 webapp and our client is upgrading their os with Office 2013. Would there be any compatibility issues when uploading and downloading document from Document library of our SharePoint app.

Do you guys foresee any concerns of any compatibility issues. Probably any new formats with aren't available with SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine there being any problems, Office2013 does not use a different file format, it's just a new interface.

There are some new integration features between Office2013 and SharePoint2013 which your client will not have access to in SharePoint 2010, but they certainly won't impact on the functionality of your existing SharePoint Apps, and I can't imagine anyone even noticing that they don't have access to a new feature that they never had before!